# F# / .NET null instance oddity

Tags: c#, .net, f#

I have this C# DLL:

```
namespace TestCSProject
{
    public class TestClass
    {
        public static TestClass Instance = null;

        public int Add(int a, int b)
        {
            if (this == null)
                Console.WriteLine("this is null");
            return a + b;
        }
    }
}
```

And this F# app which references the DLL:

```
open TestCSProject
printfn "%d" (TestClass.Instance.Add(10,20))
```

No-one initiates the `Instance` static variable. Guess what the output of the F# app is?

```
this is null
30
Press any key to continue . . .
```

After a few tests I found out that unless I use `this` (e.g. to access instance field), I won't get NullReferenceExpcetion.

Is that an intended behaviour or a gap in F# compilation / CLR?

Comment: +1: oh wow, that's something I haven't seen before :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suspect you'll find it's using `call` instead of `callvirt` if you look at the IL. The C# compiler always uses `callvirt`, even for non-virtual methods, because it forces a nullity check.

Is this a bug? Well, not necessarily. It depends on what the F# language specification states about methods calls on null references. It's perfectly possible that it states that the method will be called (non-virtually) with a null "this" reference, which is exactly what has happened.

C# happens to specify that this sort of dereferencing will throw a `NullReferenceException`, but that's a language choice.

I suspect the F# approach may be a little faster, due to the lack of nullity checking involved... and don't forget that null references are less "expected" in F# than in C#... that *may* explain the different approach taken here. Or it could just be an oversight, of course.

EDIT: I'm not an expert at reading the F# specification, but section 6.9.6 at least *suggests* to me that it's a bug:

> 6.9.6        Evaluating Method Applications
>
> For elaborated applications of methods, the elaborated form of the expression will be 
>   either expr.M(args) or M(args).
>
> - The (optional) expr and args are evaluated in left-to-right order and the body of the member is evaluated in an environment with formal parameters that are mapped to corresponding argument values.
> - If expr evaluates to null then NullReferenceException is raised.
> - If the method is a virtual dispatch slot (that is, a method that is declared abstract) then the body of the member is chosen according to the dispatch maps of the value of expr.

Whether this counts as an elaborated application or not is a little beyond me, I'm afraid... but I hope this has been at least somewhat helpful.

Comment: You're right and your explanantion sounds pretty reasonable. Different MSIL instruction was generated. I wasn't aware that it's possible to call methods in .NET in non-virtual way. Thanks Jon

Comment: @Elephantik: Interestingly, you can use `call` in IL to call virtual methods non-virtually, breaking encapsulation. (It's how C# calls to `base.Foo()` work internally.)

Comment: Indeed. see also http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/29/putting-a-base-in-the-middle.aspx for some particularly ugly corner-case behavior.

Comment: @kvb: I was thinking of exactly that blog post, but didn't have the energy to find it :)

Answer (score 3):

I think that the F# team considers this behavior a bug that is likely to change in a future release.

Occasionally a class may change a method from non-virtual (in release N) to virtual (in release N+1).  Is this a "breaking change"?  It is breaking if code compiled against the original class used `call` rather than `callvirt`.  The concept of "breaking change" is mostly a matter of *degree* rather than *kind*; the non-virtual to virtual change is a "minor" breaking change.  In any case, some classes in the .NET Framework have exhibited this kind of change, and thus you run into a problem analogous to the "fragile base class".  Witnessing this, the F# team intends to change the compiler codegen to use `callvirt` like C# and VB do.  Assuming that happens, a few unlikely programs, such as the one in this repro, would change behavior when compiled with a future version of the F# compiler.

Comment: IMHO, I find it a little shocking that the CLR considers it valid MSIL to bypass an override by using call instead of callvirt. What I'd love to see is the rationale for this being consider valid MSIL.