# Using C# library in an F# project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, f#, reference

I'm fresh to F#, but I really want to learn it. I know Python, I know C#. As a matter of fact, I've got a C# library that I've made myself; it's an wrapper for the Rdio API (I've named it RdioSharp) that I can successfully bring into another C# project and call it, use it, get data... it works.

I want to get started toying around with this C# library in an F# project, but it's not working right. Here's a brief snipped of what the C# code looks like.

```
namespace RdioSharp {
    public class RdioManager {
        public RdioManager() { }
    }
}
```

I've added the reference to the DLL in my `FSharpTest` project, I've pulled up a `.fsx` file, and I've tried the following, each line below (again, keep in mind, I really have no idea what I'm doing).

```
open RdioSharp
open RdioSharp.dll
#r "RdioSharp.dll"
#r "C:\Path\To\Library\RdioSharp.dll"
```

I can't figure this one out. I know how to use system F# libraries, but how do I reference a C# library in F#? Is it possible? Is this enough information to go on?

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752841/f-net-null-instance-oddity) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102472/f-c-fsx-script-files-and-project-references) (which gets even closer to my problem) but those folks all know more about F# than I do, and they're way ahead of my problem.

In the interactive window, when punching in `#r "RdioSharp.dll";;` , I get this lovely error.

```
error FS0084: Assembly reference 'RdioSharp.dll' was not found or is invalid
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following code works if F# environment can find the location of `Rdiosharp.dll`. Usually not! So it does not work and tells you that "error FS0084: Assembly reference 'RdioSharp.dll' was not found or is invalid".

```
#r "RdioSharp.dll"
```

You can provide the exact path of this dll as in:

```
#r @"c:\temp\RdioSharp.dll"
```

or you can add its folder into search-path:

```
#I @"c:\temp"
```

Comment: Ahh, thank you! In all my frustration, I had forgotten to `@` my string to ensure the backslashes were escaped. No wonder it couldn't find my library.

Comment: thank you!! after a couple of hours I found your answer & it solved it!